# How to install a particular plugin in IntelliJ Idea that cannot be found?

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-plugin

How to install the Lombok plugin in IntelliJ Idea? If I try to search for it in Settings -> Plugins, there is no plugin like Lombok?

[image]

Comment: Since IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3, the lombok plugin is part of IntelliJ IDEA itself. No need for installing a plugin.

Comment: More information on the plugin's features and required IntelliJ configuration: https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin#lombok-intellij-plugin-

Answer (score 7):

It's is not displayed there because you have most likely the plugin already installed. These plugins are no more displayed in the `Marketplace` tab. Check out the `Installed` tab instead:

[image]